# angular ng-model don't update on dirty value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

i would like to know if it's possible to 'prevent' an update of an form field (input, select....) that it's dirty due to user interaction.
If i update the ng-model primitive (ie: set pippo from 1 to X) the input
will get updated even if i manually edit the control.

It's possible to prevent that?

```
demo page:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ClXoS7YVcEDtcApsNpde
```

the input field count UP every X secs.
if i enter "AAA" i would like that update STOP, because
the input it's "dirty" due to user interaction.

Comment: just add the validation inside `this.update` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ngModelController to tell if the input is dirty. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Modified your plunker to http://plnkr.co/edit/oJMrQZLugnzisqdXScvN?p=preview 
The update function looks like

```
this.update = function() {
    if(!$scope.frmPippo.pippo.$dirty)
      $scope.pippo += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got the question maybe this is what you are trying to do?

```
$scope.$watch("pippo", function(){
  if($scope.pippotmp != $scope.pippo)
     $scope.useredited = true;
});
```

**UPDATED Answer**

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/h77zksBWTtqK9NWvY2R5?p=preview)

you could keep the model separated from that input changes... in a temporary variable

Comment: nope, i can't cancel interval, and AAA it's a user input, can be anything. The things is "user have modified the input" "user has not modified the input value"

Answer (score 0):

add `ngChange` attribute on input element,

[Update Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZWjOqeDMefKemmcVc8OT?p=preview)

```
 <input type=text ng-model="pippo" ng-change="userChanged()"/>

 //controller
 $scope.pippo = 1;
 $scope.isUserChanged = false;
 $scope.counter= 1;

 $scope.userChanged = function(){
    $scope.isUserChanged = true;
 }

 this.update = function() {
    if(!$scope.isUserChanged){
        $scope.pippo += 1;
    }
 }
 $interval(this.update, 3000);
```

`userChanged` would be called when user typing, but would not be called when `pippo` changed by other methods in controller, so we could set a flag in `userChanged` to indicate whether the input has been overwrite by user

Answer (score 0):

I might get the question wrong, but if I understand you correctly, then ng-model-option is what you are looking for.

For example, you can update the model only when the user leave the input
    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"

You can read more about it in the doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions